# Error Message in RStudio, but code still works?

Tags: r, error-handling, rstudio

I am new to RStudio and did the following:

```
star$small <- as.integer(star$gkclasst == 1)
```

Now I get the following error message:

```
> star$small <- as.integer(star$gkclasst == 1)
Error in exists(cacheKey, where = .rs.WorkingDataEnv, inherits = FALSE) : 
  invalid first argument
Error in assign(cacheKey, frame, .rs.CachedDataEnv) : 
  attempt to use zero-length variable name
```

But when I look at the data, I got the new column and the correct values in it.

Do you have any idea, what the problem is? Did I something wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue related to RStudio, you could fix it by downloading the latest RStudio version : https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/13188. Your code is fine.